# Error relationship persistence using Spring Data JPA in a many to one

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I have the following code for many to many or many to one relationship persistence using Spring JPA.

This is my repository test https://github.com/Truebu/testJpa.git

This class has three one-to-many relationships, but none work well

```java
@Entity(name = "routine_assignament")
@Table(name = "routine_assignament")
public class RoutineAssignament {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "date_start",nullable = true,columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private Date date_start = new Date();

    @Column(name = "date_end",nullable = true,columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private Date date_end;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_routine")
    private Routine routine;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "routine_assignament")
    private Set<Score> scores = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "routine_assignament")
    private Set<Statistic> statistics = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "routine_assignament")
    private Set<KeepRoutine> keepRoutines = new HashSet<>();
```

The other classes

```java
@Entity(name = "score")
@Table(name = "score")
public class Score {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "commentary",nullable = false,columnDefinition = "TEXT", unique = true)
    private String commentary;

    @Column(name = "assessment",nullable = false,columnDefinition = "INT", unique = true)
    private String assessment;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_routine_assignament")
    private RoutineAssignament routineAssignament;

}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "statistic")
@Table(name = "statistic")
public class Statistic {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "time",nullable = false,columnDefinition = "TEXT", unique = true)
    private String time;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_routine_assignament")
    private RoutineAssignament routineAssignament;

}
```

and

```java
@Entity(name = "keep_routine")
@Table(name = "keep_routine")
public class KeepRoutine {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_routine_assignament")
    private RoutineAssignament routineAssignament;

}
```

The entity relationship diagram is this:

[image]

My mistake is that it doesn't detect these relationships correctly.

When I run it it generates this:

```
Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.example.demo.model.entities.KeepRoutine.routine_assignament in com.example.demo.model.entities.RoutineAssignament.keepRoutines
```

This error is reproduced with all three classes (KeepRoutine, Statistic and Score), I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `OneToMany` mapping is not appropriate. You need to use `routineAssignament` the property name instead of the table name `routine_assignament` as shown below. This property name is defined in the `ManyToOne` relationship.

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "routineAssignament")
    private Set<Score> scores = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "routineAssignament")
    private Set<Statistic> statistics = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "routineAssignament")
    private Set<KeepRoutine> keepRoutines = new HashSet<>();
```